# caching fault and advantage

Tags: asp.net, caching

I search a lot but cannot find complete answer or paper about caching.

I use asp.net 4.5 and work with 3 layers to create website.

I want to know about ***cach***,***types*** and ***fault***,***advantage***.when I cach a **usercontrol** in asp.net what save in cach and other things.

I know **primary** about it but i want **advanced**.
please give me a link of Comprehensive and powerfull paper or article about it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below link,

[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/caching-in-Asp-Net/[^]](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/caching-in-Asp-Net/)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_data_caching.htm

[Caching in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6158/Caching-in-ASP-NET)